# Vue.js - How to set multiple values (array) for a component over a property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have some vue.js components, all these components get their data from outside.

Example:

```
<vue-button icon="fa-arrow-right" text="mytext"></vue-button>
```

This works great so far but now I have to set multiple values over the property.

This does not work:

```
<vue-list items="['Entry1', 'Entry2']"></vue-list>
```

How can I set multiple values over one property?

---

## Update

I have a working example but I am not sure if thats the right way to go but it works. If someone knows a better way I would be happy if you share it with me/us.

This is how I call the component:

```
<vue-list times='[ "08:00 - 12:00", "13:00 - 21:00" ]'></vue-list>
```

And this is the code of the component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="item in timesArray">
            <span v-html="item"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['times'],
    data: function() {
        return {
            timesArray: [],
        }
    },
    created: function() {
        this.timesArray = JSON.parse(this.times);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just use :items or v-bind:items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the attribute binding syntax.

```
<vue-list :times='[ "08:00 - 12:00", "13:00 - 21:00" ]'></vue-list>
```

Note the colon in front of `:times`. You don't need to parse or use data.

Answer (score 0):

It is not because you missed to close the Entry 2 string?

```
<vue-list items="['Entry1', 'Entry2]"></vue-list>
```

The right code is

```
<vue-list items="['Entry1', 'Entry2']"></vue-list>
```

Think it should work if the component logic is okay.

Comment: No sorry, thanks for the correction. It was just a typo here on stackoverflow. It always comes as a string to the component not as an array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass it using an vue instance variable only, see this [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/4cc9buft/).

```
<div id="app">
  <child  :items="items"></child>
</div>
```

where items in defined as vue instance data:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    full_name: "Initial Val",
    items: ['Entry1', 'Entry2']
  }
})
```

Comment: But if I use data I cant set it from outside as property.